# Can't get Devise path correct

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I installed Devise to get authentication into my application.  I followed all the instructions about the gem and that part seemed to go well.

However now that I am trying to link to the Register page, I get a crazy error I can't figure out...  For some reason, rails can't figure out where the devise controllers are located...

from:  public/index.html.erb (public landing page)

```
<div class ="getstarted">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td id = "introtext"> 
        <p>Foo is good..l here is why: </p>
        <ul>
          <li>Improved quality</li>
          <li>Technology consistencies </li>
          <li>Cost efficiencies</li>
          <li>Increased security</li>
         <li>Improved adherence to compliance standards</li>
       </ul>    

      </td>
      <td id = "buttons">
        <%= button_to "Sign Up for an Account", new_user_registration_path, :method => "get" %>
        <br/>
        <%= button_to "Log In to your Account", new_user_session_path, :controller => "devise/session", :method => "get" %>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</div>
```

routes.rb has the following line:

```
 devise_for :users
```

and the Routes table seems to have what it needs:

```
    new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)                                   devise/sessions#new
        user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)                                   devise/sessions#create
destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)                                  devise/sessions#destroy
       user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)                                  devise/passwords#create
   new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)                              devise/passwords#new
  edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)                             devise/passwords#edit
                     PUT    /users/password(.:format)                                  devise/passwords#update
```

cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)                                    devise/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                                           devise/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)                                   devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                                      devise/registrations#edit
                         PUT    /users(.:format)                                           devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)                                          devise/registrations#destroy

When I click on the button to register I go to the link:

```
http://localhost:3000/users/sign_up?
```

and Rails gives me the error:

```
No route matches {:controller=>"devise/public"}
```

Same thing for the log-in button:

```
http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in?

No route matches {:controller=>"devise/public"}
```

I set up a view for "public" to be my public viewable (pre authentication) pages... and I see that Rails is looking for that inside the devise directory (which doesn't exist).

I also tried deleting the ? at the end of the URL... that didn't produce any difference.

I'm stuck and a couple hours already invested.  Hope someone can help me out.

Comment: Couple of things: (1) in this case, you don't need to specify the `:method` or the `:controller` in your links above unless you have overridden the Devise controllers. (2) have you restarted your server since implementing Devise?

Comment: Strange.  In my application.html.erb I have the block
`<% if current_page?(:controller => 'public') %>
  < div class = "container2">
<%  else %>
  <div class="container">
<% end %>`
It seems that this is setting the controller to "public" - if I remove this logic, it works fine.

Comment: All's well that ends well.

Answer (score 1):

For your "Log in to your account" button, I would change the current route from '**new_user_session_path**,' to '**user_session_path**'.

Also I would change 'button_to' into '**link_to**'

See what that does